# jQuery UI Autocomplete - How to tell if "autocompleteopen" event is triggered when the suggestion menu is opened or updated?

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, autocomplete

jQuery UI Autocomplete has a method called "autocompleteopen" that is [Triggered when the suggestion menu is opened or updated](http://api.jqueryui.com/autocomplete/#event-open).

I need to tell if this event is being called  when the menu is opened or updated, and perform differently upon each operation. Is it possible?

Here's an example with more details. I'm using [Autocomplete's custom combobox](http://jqueryui.com/autocomplete/#combobox) to improve layout and functionality of select fields. On this combobox, there's two methods to show the options of dropdown menu:

1. First one is to simply click on the rightbutton and all options will be shown.
2. Second one is to type something on the text field on the left, and only matched results will be shown.

Both methods trigger "autocompleteopen" event, but on the first one, the menu is simply opened, and on the second one, the menu is updated.

I just need to tell inside event if the menu is simply opened, or if it's updated. If opened, I activate some fadein transitions on the menu and trigger some additional events. If updated, no transition and additional events are triggered.

Comment: Could you go into more detail regarding what you mean by the menu being "opened" vs "updated?" What are the differences you're looking for?

Comment: I've updated the question inserting more details. Please take a look again.

Comment: Can you place your fadeIn transitions and additional logic after the .click() event of the right button, instead of reacting to the autocompleteopen event? That will guarantee that the "open" scenario is being invoked.

Comment: @DanielSimpkins Good idea! In theory, that'll solve the fadein transitions problem, but dunno about my additional events. I'll try that later.